# How to specifically call html for Safari only

Tags: php, wordpress, browser, if-statement, safari

I am using Wordpress and my index page has responsive html on it that does not agree with safari however I created html that will work with Safari is there a php if statement that I can use to call that html ?

I used a plugin for this in Wordpress but the plugin does not work when its activated "Source Redirect Site".

Regular html - "173.83.251.7/~grebesba/" Safari Specific 173.83.251.7/~grebesba/5453-2/

Im looking for a php code that would be

"* php> ..... the regular code

if else? the safari specific code

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the user agent:

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if( strpos( $user_agent, 'Safari' ) !== false ){
    // do Safari stuff
}
```

Comment: What would be the correct code to redirect a specific url? And were would I place this particular code?

Comment: You can use it in any template, or in `functions.php`. To redirect, check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect. If you perform a redirect from a template, make sure to do it before the `get_header` call.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the answer you were looking for, but:

A better solution would be to track down the javascript/css/markup-bug. Doing hacks for just one browser is ugly and may end up causing more problems in the long run.

Comment: that does not make any sense